# Reactive subscription on user collection

Tags: meteor, angular-meteor

I am trying to subscribe to profdle information of a different user than the logged in user, but I am facing issues as mentioned below
I am using angular-material and my code looks like below:

```
//publish user info upon following user
Meteor.publish("getUserInfo", function (userId) {
    return (Meteor.users.find({_id: userId}, {fields: {profile: 1}}));
});

//subscribe
 $scope.$meteorSubscribe("getUserInfo", askLikeController.$root.askLike[0].userId).then(function (subscriptionHandle) {
            //Second element in the userProfile array will have the profile of required user
            askLikeController.$root.usersProfile = $meteor.collection(Meteor.users, false);   
        });
```

Issues:
1. In the variable askLikeController.$root.usersProfile, I am getting both the loggedIn user and the desired userinfo having userId, I was expecting userinfo of only desired userId, why is this?
2. The subscription "getUserInfo" is not reactive, and even the subscription is lost after processing few blocks of code and then in the askLikeController.$root.usersProfile I am left with only user profile of logged in user, my guess is that my subscription is being replaced by inbuilt Meteor subscription for user.

How do I solve the issues?

Regards,
Chidan

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have removed autopublish:

```
> meteor remove autopublish
```

To get reactivity in angular-meteor you need `$meteor.autorun` and `$scope.getReactively`. Here's an example:

```
// we need the requested id in a scope variable
// anytime the scope var changes, $scope.getReactively will
// ... react!
$scope.reqId = askLikeController.$root.askLike[0].userId;

$meteor.autorun($scope, function() {
    $scope.$meteorSubscribe('getUserInfo', $scope.getReactively('reqId')));
}).then(function(){
    askLikeController.$root.usersProfile = $meteor.collection(Meteor.users, false);   
})
```

Getting only the user you selected: NOTICE- the logged in users is *always* published. So you need to specify which user you want to look at on the client side, just like you did on the publish method. So, in the subscribe method:

```
askLikeController.$root.usersProfile = $meteor.collection(function() {
    return Meteor.Users.find({_id: $scope.getReactively('reqId')})
```

}, false);

At this point you might be better off changing it to an object rather than a collection:

```
askLikeController.$root.usersProfile = $scope.$meteorObject(Meteor.Users, {_id: $scope.getReactively('reqId')});
```

Comment: Hi Tj, now I am able to get the desired user in askLikeController.$root.usersProfile but this variable is not reactive, that is my second issue still remains. Once subscribed I am going to db and changing the user profile of the subscribed user but this is not getting updated in the client subscription? Any ideas/clues?

Comment: Hi TJ, I think I found the reason but not answer, Meteor is only having cursor pointing to currently logged on user, hence when I change the profile of currently logged on user the profile is also changed in the client. And the cursor for the desired user is run only for the first time of subscription. Now question is how to make sure that the cursor still points to "getUserInfo" subscription and not the default subscription of user

Comment: That's what the publish function `getUserInfo` is supposed to be doing. what does your `getUserInfo` publish function look like?